# A different virtualenv for each Django app

Tags: python, django, virtualenv

In Django, a project can contain many apps. Can each app have its own virtualenv? Or do all the apps in a Django project have to use the project's virtualenv?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The entire project is loaded into the same Python process. You can't have two Python environments active at the same time in the same process. So the answer is no - you can't have concurrent virtual environments for apps in the same project.